# Disable button if input length less than 3

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

I want to **disable** button if input **length is less than 3**:

```
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newListItem">
 <button [disabled]="{ disabled : newListItem.length < 3 }"></button>
```

But this code doesn't work. How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: This is a valid question, with good answers. I would just caution people who find this question while implementing Name input fields not to restrict length https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You only need to pass an expression to `disabled` property, there's no need to create object:

```
<button [disabled]="newListItem.length < 3"></button>
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined if i try your method i just have a input type and button

Comment: @Kannan add a check if newListItem is defined  "newListItem && newListItem.length < 3" will suggest an edit.

Comment: or today, thanks to the Optional chaining `(?.)` operator, in a slightly less verbose way:
`newListItem?.length < 3`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

<button [disabled]="validateLength()">

validateLength() { return this.newListItem.length < 3; }